# Make blender unaware of user/system installed add-ons

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, customization

I am running a customized, local install of blender from and with a script:

`./blender --background --python generator-blender.py --`

My customized local install of blender is prepared with add-ons that might also be present in the user/system add-on locations, which currently leads me to (e.g.) `blend4web` being found once as a locally installed add-on and once more as a user-installed add-on:

```
multiple addons with the same name:
'/home/simonrepp/AXIOM/elmyra/lib/linux/blender-2.76b-linux-glibc211-x86_6/2.76/scripts/addons/blend4web/__init__.py'
'/home/simonrepp/.config/blender/2.76/scripts/addons/blend4web/__init__.py'
```

How can I tell blender to ignore the user/system installed add-ons and rely solely on what is present in the local install i have set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my customized, local install I needed to create an empty `config/` folder inside the `2.XX/` folder (the one that contains `datafiles/`, `python/`, `scripts/` already - in my case `2.67/`). As soon as blender sees this folder it completely ignores any user/system add-ons (and everything else too I suppose - startup files, configuration, etc.)

I found the answer here: [Need guidance for creating no dependancies between two installs of Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/need-guidance-for-creating-no-dependancies-between-two-installs-of-blender)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! This will be useful for other B4W users too.